# CSS - If element has ANY class

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to hide an element with CSS, if body has any class applied to it.

```
<body class="x"> - element should hide
<body class="a"> - element should hide
<body> - element should show
```

This element should appear if body is classless or has the class .page-home,

but otherwise, the element should be hidden.

I've tried the universal selector:

```
#body.* .withicon {
display:none;
}

.page-home .withicon {
display:block;
}
```

which didn't work,

I've tried tricks like

```
.withicon {
display:none;
}

.page-home .withicon {
display:block;
}

.withicon:not([class]) {
display:none;
}
```

But I cant seem to get it working, at all.

Comment: I didn't understand so well. Your element has to be displayed or not if the body has or not a class. But how can your body pass from no-class to a class?

Comment: @JoshCrozier That seems to have worked! Thanks.

Comment: @Adrian
I agree, that's only gonna happen with JS.
And with JS this it's very easy to do what OP wants.
var showThis = document.querySelector(".whiticon");
var classOrNoClass = document.getElementById(bodyID);
if (classrNoClass.classList !== ""){
showThis.style.opacity = 1}
else{showThis.style.opacity = 0};
Of course this means removing the disply none property and we'd need to know which eventListener to use.

Comment: Even using JS, he has to declare a condition for assigning a class to body and another one to take it down. When it has this two conditions he can declare the statement where he says when the element should be displayed or not

Comment: Why wouldn't this work? `.withicon {display:none;} .page-home .withicon {display:block;}` this should work as expected... without the need for all these extra conditional codes

Comment: @Aziz: That displays the element only when `body` (or the parent) has `class='page-home'`. It doesn't display the element if the body is classless and this was one of OP's requirements (*This element should appear if body is classless or has the class .page-home*).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The `.withicon` element should appear if `body` is classless or has the class `.page-home`

Based on the selectors in your question, it seems like you want the following:

```
.withicon {
  display: none;
}

body:not([class]) .withicon,
.page-home .withicon {
  display: block;
}
```

You were negating `.withicon` elements with a class attribute when you should have been negating the `body` element if it had a class attribute using the selector `body:not([class])`.

In other words, the selector `body:not([class]) .withicon` will select the `.withicon` descendant elements if the `body` element doesn't have a class attribute.

Comment: While `[class]` should be translated by the browser to `[class=""]` by default, it may be safer to add the `=""` yourself in rule: `body:not([class=""])`". I have seen it gone wrong (can't remember where)...

Comment: @RenevanderLende That's definitely interesting. Do you know of any documentation stating that? I'm curious..

Comment: `[class]` and `[class=""]` have different meanings, and it’s the former that is needed here.

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ctm36hgt/) for what @JukkaK.Korpela stated above. [class] points to all elements which has `class` as an attribute whereas [class=""] points only to elements which have a `class` attribute with no value. They are not the same and so there is no need to change Josh's answer.